# Why is my Python venv directory read-only?

Tags: python, windows, powershell, readonly, python-venv

I am new to virtual envs in Python. I am using Python 3.9 on Windows 10, and an admin Powershell prompt (through `cmder`).

I created a new directory named `toto`, set it as current directry (`$ cd toto`), and ran the following command :

```
$  python -m venv env
```

So far so good. But then I want to activate the virtual environment, using the following command :

```
$ .\env\Scripts\Activate.ps1
```

But it seems that the `env` directory and its content is read-only (Windows file system indicates so), and I get the following error (poorly translated from french to english) :

```
+ CategoryInfo          : WriteError: (prompt:String) [Copy-Item], SessionStateUnauthorizedAccessException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : FunctionNotWritable,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.CopyItemCommand

Impossible to write in the prompt fonction, because it is constant or read-only.
At character D:\outils\PyperGraph\env\Scripts\Activate.ps1:227 : 5
+     function global:prompt {
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      + CategoryInfo          : WriteError: (prompt:String) [], SessionStateUnauthorizedAccessException
      + FullyQualifiedErrorId : FunctionNotWritable
```

Why is this happening, and how to fix this issue ?

Comment: Try using `.\env\Scripts\activate` and see if its the same error

Comment: @dfundako : same error, sadly

Comment: It could be helpful to mention in the question that you used cmder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aaaaand I enventually figured it out. The issue was quite specific : it is due to the terminal I use, which is [`cmder`](https://cmder.net/) (a terminal emulator which adds several fonctionnalities to the defaults windows `cmd`, `powershell` and others).

Issue is discussed [[here]](https://github.com/cmderdev/cmder/issues/1207), and the fix appears to comment the line which contains `-Options ReadOnly` in the `cmder` profile file: `cmder_path\vendor\profile.ps1`.

Tested and approved, everything works fine now.

Another workaround could also be not to use `cmder` for `venv`.

Comment: Man, you are a life saver. I exclusively use cmder in Windows as my main terminal, and this ends up being the source of many headaches.

Your solution worked flawslessly, and this also solved the problem of the "venv" prefix not appearing at the beginning of each terminal line when you are using a virtual environment.
Thank you so much!